# Why can't work be done by dark energy on cosmic scales?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, dark-energy

My rudimentary understanding of dark energy as the cosmological constant is that the vacuum state of space has positive energy but negative/repulsive gravity/pressure.

Given a system dominated by "positive" gravity like a planet or solar system, "positive" gravity wins out and the system doesn't expand.

But in deep space is there some sweet spot (or shell) where a system is prevented from clumping purely due to its own rigidity and the negative pressure of dark energy? I'm imagining a thin rigid structure like the edges and vertices of a dodecahedron that dissipates heat outwards and uses the constant negative pressure (a constant force? It is gravity after all  right? -- it's part of the curvature of spacetime) to do work and continually repair itself.

Is this structure prevented soley because no material is that rigid and low mass?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about [Einstein's static Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%27s_static_universe), a model of the Universe in which the "collapsing tendency" of matter of uniform density and the "expanding tendency" of a cosmological constant are perfectly balanced, leading to a static solution.  However, this solution turns out to be unstable;  a small perturbation is enough push it away from this equilibrium.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert that is along the lines I am curious about. Why our universe *must* tend toward heat death and all ty

Answer (score 1):

A crude answer is "nothing is that big".

The cosmological constant has a value of $10^{-52}$ m$^{-2}$ (in units where $c=1$, so I hope I do this right...). So the approximate linear scale we are talking about before those effects become important is $\sim 10^{26} m$. The largest structures in the universe are Galactic super clusters, which are ~millions of light years across. In units of $c=1$, that's

$$\sim 10^{6} \text{ly}~ c (\pi \times 10^7\text{ s/yr })\sim 10^{13}~m$$

($\pi \times 10^{7}$ is the approximate number of seconds in a year). So if I did that right, the largest structures we know in the universe are about a ten thousand billion times too small for the cosmological constant to play an important role.

Comment: That is outlandishly big. I think I can safely say that something big can never be built and have run out of ideas to fight the heat death. Ty